# How to use UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentinteraction

I have created a program that loads PDF files. I want when the user is editing that they can publish the file anywhere in PDF format.

Do I use `UIDocumentInteractionController` or use `UIActivityViewController`?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)

class PDFViewControllerEN: UIViewController {
    var document: UIDocumentInteractionController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // retrieve URL to file in main bundle`
    }

    @IBOutlet var pdfview: UIView!

    @IBAction func share(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func doAction2(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        document.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.bounds, in: view, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Here you are going to display your PdfController
        //PDFController that is seprate class you had created to show pdf file being opened
        //i.e

        //check which button was being selected
        switch ButtonSelected.Tag {
        case 0:
            var document: UIDocumentInteractionController = {
                let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "EN1", withExtension: "pdf")

                let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)
                pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
                view.addSubview(pdfView)
                vc.delegate = self

                return vc
            }()
            //  document.presentPreview(animated: true)
            break
        case 1:
            //here control when you selected button with tag 0
            //here need to open pdf AR2
            //set Frame here all bounds

            var document: UIDocumentInteractionController = {
                let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "EN2", withExtension: "pdf")

                let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)
                pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
                view.addSubview(pdfView)
                vc.delegate = self

                return vc
            }()
            break
        case 2:
            //here control when you selected button with tag 0
            //here need to open pdf AR2
            //set Frame here all bounds

            var document: UIDocumentInteractionController = {
                let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

                let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "EN3", withExtension: "pdf")

                let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)
                pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
                view.addSubview(pdfView)
                vc.delegate = self

                return vc
            }()
            break
        default:
            //Error Case
            print("No tag Value Available")
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
extension PDFViewControllerEN: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using UIDocumentInteractionController is quite easy. You just need to know the url of your file, then you present the menu:

```
/// Needs to be global, otherwise the controller will be destroyed when the file is handed over to target application
var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var url: URL

    ...

    @IBAction func share(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
        documentInteractionController.url = url
        documentInteractionController.uti = url.uti
        documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: sender, animated: true)
    }

}

extension URL {

    var uti: String {
        return (try? self.resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data"
    }

}
```

Comment: i got error `Class 'PDFViewControllerEN' has no initializers`

Comment: i got this error when i clicked the button `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

Comment: My answer was meant as an example for how to call the UIDocumentInteractionController inside a ViewController. You cannot copy the code without initialization and additional functions for the ViewController. Please provide your full code for help.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried and explained in detail about `UIDocumentInteractionController`. Refer this link if you want to check the details.

> https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/managing-files-in-ios-dfcdfdc1f426

**Code**

```
extension ViewController {
    /// This function will set all the required properties, and then provide a preview for the document
    func share(url: URL) {
        documentInteractionController.url = url
        documentInteractionController.uti = url.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data, public.content"
        documentInteractionController.name = url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent
        documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
    }

    /// This function will store your document to some temporary URL and then provide sharing, copying, printing, saving options to the user
    func storeAndShare(withURLString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: withURLString) else { return }
        /// START YOUR ACTIVITY INDICATOR HERE
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            let tmpURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
                .appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "fileName.png")
            do {
                try data.write(to: tmpURL)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                /// STOP YOUR ACTIVITY INDICATOR HERE
                self.share(url: tmpURL)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    /// If presenting atop a navigation stack, provide the navigation controller in order to animate in a manner consistent with the rest of the platform
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        guard let navVC = self.navigationController else {
            return self
        }
        return navVC
    }
}

extension URL {
    var typeIdentifier: String? {
        return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier
    }
    var localizedName: String? {
        return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName
    }
}
```

**Calling**

```
@IBAction func showOptionsTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    /// Passing the remote URL of the file, to be stored and then opted with mutliple actions for the user to perform
    storeAndShare(withURLString: "https://images5.alphacoders.com/581/581655.jpg")
}
```

**Note**

> https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/

Before your files can appear in the **Files** app, you must indicate that your app supports Open in Place and File Sharing Enabled. These options are configured using keys in your Info.plist file.

The first key is `UIFileSharingEnabled`, which enables iTunes sharing of files in your Documents folder.

The second key is `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`, which grants the local file provider access to files in your Documents folder.

Add these keys to your Info.plist and set their values to YES.

Comment: super explanation @Mansi

Comment: Glad you found it useful @SPatel

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19532313)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks, added.

Comment: How would you handle a temporary file? I figured `documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu()` is called also when you, say share in Messages, cancel that, and the `UIDocumentInteractionController` shows again. There is no method in the delegate protocol that is called when the interaction controller is dismissed for good. I wonder when a temporary file could be removed.

Comment: doing this can get your app rejected if you store other app related files there

Comment: @user2899094 where are we storing other app’s data ? Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 4):

Silly case but might help to someone.

To anyone who can't save files check if your controller is alive. My problem was that my `UIDocumentInteractionController` was destroyed after it was closed.

*Here's how my function looked like:*

```
private func showDocumentInteractionController(url: URL) {
     let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
     documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
     documentInteractionController.delegate = self
}
```

The fix is to make sure that `UIDocumentInteractionController` is alive after it closes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    private let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController()

    private func showDocumentInteractionController(url: URL) {
       documentInteractionController.url = url
       documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
       documentInteractionController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work which shows a PDF file:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { [self] in
            guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "YOUR_PDF_FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION", withExtension: "pdf") else { return }
            let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: path)
            documentInteractionController.delegate = self
            documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
        }

    }
}

extension ViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
}
```